# Was ist das Antonym von ‚Fachwort‘?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, antonym

Gibt es in der deutschen Sprache ein festes Antonym von *Fachwort*? Ein Wort für Worte der Umgangssprache?

Comment: Nein, es gibt kein Fachwort für kein Fachwort.

Comment: Was wäre mit _Laienbegriff_ oder _-ausdruck_?

Comment: Was ist mit _Begriff aus dem Volksmund_?

Comment: @jera Warum nicht gleich _*Volkswort_?

Comment: @Crissov Womöglich kann man die zwei Wörter _Volk_ und _Wort_ so zusammensetzen. Geläufig ist mir das aber nicht.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass es leichter fällt eine Antwort zu geben, wenn du mehrere Beispiele für Begriffe nennst, die deiner Meinung nach keine Fachworte sind.

Comment: @jera Deswegen das Sternchen

Comment: @Crissov Oho, ich kenne das Sternchen nicht... Wofür steht es denn?

Comment: @jera Das Sternchen steht für Ersetzung oder verbesserunh.

Comment: @jera *Verbesserung

Comment: @jera Nein, nicht ganz das, was Tanz Walzer meint: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/338/meaning-of-star-asterisk-in-linguistics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nicht für beliebige Begriffe aber für Namen von Dingen gibt es die Bezeichnung [Trivialname](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivialname).

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund, warum diese schöne Bezeichnung nicht auch für andere Begriffe benutzt werden sollte. Wenn es noch nicht der Fall ist, sollten wir umgehend damit anfangen!

Comment: Man sollte ergänzen, dass in der Chemie Trivialnamen (wie z.B. Aceton für Propan-2-on, Glycerin für Propan-1,2,3-triol oder Toluol für Methylbenzen) keineswegs als Nicht-Fachwörter empfunden werden. Solche Trivialnamen (wie auch Styrol, Chloroform, Phosgen) sind sehr wohl Fachbegriffe. (Das steht zwar auch so im Wikipedia-Artikel, sollte man in der Antwort aber auch erwähnen.)

Answer (score 4):

Ich schlage

> Profanbegriff

vor. [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-bin/wort_www.exe?site=2&Wort_id=8300914) nennt für *profan* u. a. die Bedeutungen *laienhaft* und *alltäglich*, auch wenn eine kirchliche Note mitschwingt.